# Как правильно обновлять информацию в дочернем элементе vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Вопрос следующий. Представим есть компонет календаря, в котором указываются какие-то даты. После нажатия на кнопку "Создать событие" появляется модальное окно, являющееся дочерним элементом. Примерно выглядит так:

```
<vuestic-modal
  :show.sync="show"
  v-bind:large="true"
  ref="largeModal"
  :okText="'modal.confirm' | translate"
  :cancelText="'modal.cancel' | translate"
>
```

В этом модальном окне множество полей для ввода информации. Хотелось бы после нажатия на кнопку создать (в этом же окне) отправить созданные даты (хранятся в storage) и введенную информацию в модальном окне.

В чем основная проблема? Хранить все в storage - не вариант, т.к. эти данные не смогут находится в v-model. Дополнительно ко всему, нужно иметь возможность изменять данные в модальном окне по клике на дату. Ввиду этого есть несколько путей, использовать props, watcher или вообще события. Не могу понять, среди моих предложений есть верное решение? Мне они все кажутся костылями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от прямого изменения данных в `$store.state` при использовании `v-model`, достаточно использовать `computed` свойства. Например:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="inputValue">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            inputValue: {
                get() {
                    return this.$store.state.myValue
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$store.commit("changeMyValue", value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Похожий трюк можно использовать для реализации `v-model` в своих компонентах

Родительский компонент

```
<template>
    <MyComponent v-model="myValue">
</template>
...
```

Компонент `MyComponent`:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="inputValue">
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "MyComponent",
        props: {
            value: String // Это свойство будет установлено при использовании v-model
        },
        computed: {
            inputValue: {
                get() {
                    return this.value
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$emit("input", value) // вызываем событие input в компоненте для обновления значения v-model в родителе
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```